# One-to-many relationship when one side is unnecessary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, entity-relationship

I have a table called **vital_sign** which belongs to a *patient* (the patient has multiple vital signs) and to a *physician* (the physician captured this vital sign), but I don't care about getting physician.vital_signs, how do I express it in rails models?

I suspect something like this:

1. **vital_signs** (belongs_to :patient, belongs_to :physician) with *patient_id*, *physician_id*
2. **patient** (has_many :vital_signs)
3. **physician** (nil)

Is this correct?

Comment: If you don't care about the physician who recorded the sign, why are you storing it at all? Why not just discard the data of which physician, rather than storing it?

Comment: I do care about who recorded the sign, but only when making something like: patient_1.vital_signs.where("LIKE 'blood-pressure').physician_id (to know who recorded it), but I don't care about getting all the vital_signs recorded by a doctor, like doctor_1.vital_signs (as this would mean to get vital_signs of different patients)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you asked. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :vital_signs
end

class VitalSign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :vital_signs
end
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't uunderstand, but where are the vital signs in this relationships?